# How to correctly specify parameter for Html.TextBoxFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, view

In case of view strongly typed with model type this works:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyModelField) %>
```

this works too:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.MyModelField) %>
```

What is the correct way and why it works in both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to specify the lambda expression is by using the first syntax. The second syntax is also supported and works but feels *heavier* because of the capturing of the `Model` instance inside the closure.

Comment: Can you point me to the description how `x` is resolved to `Model` in first expression?

Comment: @artvolk, starting from asp.net mvc 2 strongly typed helpers were introduced: [`HtmlHelper<TModel>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492619.aspx). Once you have astrongly typed your view, it derives from [`ViewPage<TModel>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470798.aspx) which in turn has a property `Html` of type `HtmlHelper<TModel>`. Now because `TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>` is an extension method for `HtmlHelper<TModel>`, the `x` inside the lambda expression points to the model. It's more a question about generics rather than something to do with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thanks, Darin! One shot -- one hit, as usual :)